# Yosemite + PCI Serial Card?

Tags: macos, mac-pro

I have a PCIe serial card in a Mac Pro based on the 16950 that's been working fine up until Yosemite. It's been working with the built-in Apple16x50Serial.kext driver.

With Yosemite, it looks like the driver loads okay, but no serial port appears under /dev/, and no IOBSDSerialClient for the card appears in ioreg either.

Anyone else have the same problem please let me know, or if you have a solution even better. :-)

Thanks

Comment: I'd write the manufacturer or check their website to see if they have, or are working on, a new driver.

Comment: I'm trying to reach out to Apple to see if they made any changes to the driver (this card uses the built-in Apple16x50Serial.kext driver). It doesn't look like it's been modified since 10.6 however (code's available now for 10.10 on the Apple open source site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was another weird Apple big - Yosemite 10.10.1 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the driver loads fine? Since Yosemite kexts need to be signed. Check the [kextstats man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kextstat.8.html) for the status of your kexts.

Check out the [TrimEnabler FAQ](http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/) -- they have quite some information on kext signing and the troubles you might experience due to this.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it loads, under System Profiler the card is listed as "driver loaded", and the driver itself is listed as "loaded".

I inspected the bundle and it appears to be validly signed- would hope so since it's Apple's driver.

It's a weird problem... seems to be something else Yosemite is doing causing things to fail. I wonder if it's a permissions issue or something strange when the driver attempts to create the device node under /dev/.